# Chebyshev filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I have to design highpass filter using cheby1 where cutoff frequency is 100 Hz this is what i came to:

```
sf=3500;%sampling frequency
T = 1/sf; 
L = 1000; % samples
t = (0:L-1)*T; 
s=sin(2*pi*85*t)+ sin(2*pi*500*t)+ sin(2*pi*1600*t);%signal

t1 = linspace(0,2*pi,200)
[b,a]   = cheby1(4,1,0.1);  
[H,w] = freqz(b,a,512);
fs = filter(b,a,s)
s = fft(s,512);
fs1= fft(fs,512);
```

And its not working, any help?

Comment: It's working. It's just that your filter is a low-pass one and not high-pass.

Comment: So how do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing an argument from cheby1. Try the following:

```
[b,a]   = cheby1( 4, 1, 0.1, 'high' );
```